# В Inline-Block выпадают блоки

Tags: html

Выпадают блоки в `.pre-footer` перед блоком футера. Не могу понять почему так происходит. Разрешение экрана `1920 x 1080`.
[Код.](https://jsfiddle.net/fmrn62za/)

Answer (score 2):

Все понял, забыл про

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

Comment: из-за этого выпадают?